# Memory issues with threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm working on a multi-threaded server application.
I have this struct that I try to pass to 2 Threads:

```
struct params{
  SafeQueue<int> *mq;
  Database *db;
};
class Server{
  Server(Database *db){
    DWORD sthread, ethread;
    params *p;
    p = new params;
    p->db = db;
    SafeQueue<int> *msgq = new SafeQueue<int>;
    p->mq = msgq;
    cout << "Address of params: " << p << endl;
    cout << "Address of SafeQueue: " << msgq << endl;
    cout << "Starting Server...\n";
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, smtpReceiver, &p, 0, &sthread); 
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, mQueue, &p, 0, &ethread);
  }
}
DWORD WINAPI mailQueue(LPVOID lpParam){
  params *p = (params *) lpParam;
  SafeQueue<int> *msgQ = p->mq;
  cout << "Address of params: " << p << endl;
  cout << "Address of SafeQueue: " << msgQ << endl;
  cout << "Queue thread started...\n";
}
```

Now the issue I'm having is the pointer to SafeQueue in the mailQueue thread has the address of the params struct... See output:

```
Address of params: 0x23878
Address of SafeQueue: 0x212c8
Starting Server...
Address of params: 0x28fe60
Address of SafeQueue: 0x23878
Queue thread started...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, mQueue, &p, 0, &ethread);
                              ^^
```

This should be just `p`

You pass a `params**` to the `mailQueue` thread then cast it to `params*` and dereference it, that's undefined behaviour.  What happens in practice is that `p->mq` is the address at `*p` (because `offsetof(params, mq) == 0`) which is the value of `p` in the `Server` constructor, as you're seeing in the `cout` output.

To fix it, you should be passing a `params*` to the new thread, i.e. the variable `p` not its address.